# Asp.net membership table access from mvc5 entity framework context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have a new app lets call it mvc5Identity app. I login to that app using asp.net identity user. In this app I have another EF Context that connects me to a web forms app database. Let's call it webformsMembershipapp now my question is

Can I specify something on EF Context to tell it that webformsMembershipapp contains membership tables so I can use something similar to userManager or Membership.getAll users to access Membership tables from mvc5Identity app.